# Sed commands modify files with special characters

Tags: sed

The project has a requirement to replace some strings with special characters in the file, such as

### Sample file - sample input

file.conf

```
bridge.mqtt.aws.mountpoint = aws/

bridge.mqtt.aws.certfile = etc/certs/client-cert.pem
```

### sed command one

i type sed command as follows

```
sed -i "s/aws/test/g" ./file.conf
```

### result one

The results are as follows

```
bridge.mqtt.test.mountpoint = test/
# The line I would expect would be `bridge.mqtt.test.mountpoint = aws/`


bridge.mqtt.test.certfile = etc/certs/client-cert.pem
```

I knew I could delete `g` to match the first one per line, but I worry that there are `multiple places in a row` that need to be matched.

### sed command two

So, I use an elongated string match, the sed command as follows
`sed -i "s/.aws./.test./g" ./file.conf`,

### result two

which failed as follows

```
bridge.mqtt.test.mountpoint =.test.
# The line I would expect would be `bridge.mqtt.test.mountpoint = aws/`

bridge.mqtt.test.certfile = etc/certs/client-cert.pem
```

How can I modify the `sed` instruction to achieve the effect I want

### desired output

Use a command like `sed command two` to get the following results
`sed`

```
bridge.mqtt.test.mountpoint = aws/

bridge.mqtt.test.certfile = etc/certs/client-cert.pem
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: All input examples that you  have given give the expected output if you simply drop the `g` modifier in your sed. Do you have any counter examples?

Comment: Also note that `.` in a regex is not the literal period, but "any character". To match a period character you have to use `\\.` or `[.]`

Comment: @knittl Your method solves the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You say that removing `g` will not work, but all examples that you have given will work as expected. You have not provided any counter examples which would not yield the expected result, so my answer is based on the assumption that you only want to replace "aws" if it is preceded by a period:

```
sed -i 's/\.aws/.test/g' ./file.conf
```

This of course will not work, if the part after the `=` character contains a period too.

Input:

```
bridge.mqtt.aws.mountpoint = aws/
bridge.mqtt.aws.certfile = etc/certs/client-cert.pem
```

Output:

```
bridge.mqtt.test.mountpoint = aws/
bridge.mqtt.test.certfile = etc/certs/client-cert.pem
```

---

Will not work with input:

```
bridge.mqtt.aws.mountpoint = /hidden/dir/.aws/
```

resulting in:

```
bridge.mqtt.test.mountpoint = /hidden/dir/.test/
```

---

But maybe the provided solution is already good enough™ for your input set.

Note that something like "aws123" will also be replaced with "test123", which might or not might be what you want to do.

More ideas

If you don't mind running the "cleanup script" multiple times in a row (e.g. is there still something to replace? -> run sed), you could do the following to only replace "aws" there's no `=` character before it):

```
sed 's/^\([^=]*\)\.aws/\1.test/g'
```